# Pass arguments to console.log as first class arguments via proxy function

Tags: javascript

`console.log` takes an unspecified number of arguments and dumps their content in a single line.

Is there a way I can write a function that passes arguments passed to it directly to `console.log` to maintain that behaviour? For example:

```
function log(){
    if(console){
        /* code here */
    }
}
```

This would not be the same as:

```
function log(){
    if(console){
        console.log(arguments);
    }
}
```

Since `arguments` is an array and `console.log` will dump the contents of that array. Nor will it be the same as:

```
function log(){
    if(console){
        for(i=0;i<arguments.length;console.log(arguments[i]),i++);
    }
}
```

Since that will print everything in different lines. The point is to maintain `console.log`'s behaviour, but through a proxy function `log`.

+---

I was looking for a solution I could apply to all functions in the future (create a proxy for a function keeping the handling of arguments intact). If that can't be done however, I'll accept a `console.log` specific answer.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This should do it ..

```
function log() {
    if(typeof(console) !== 'undefined') {
        console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    }
}
```

---

Just adding another option (*using the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator and the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) parameters - although `arguments` could be used directly with the spread*)

```
function log(...args) {
    if(typeof(console) !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(...args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Chrome/Safari. It throws an "Illegal invocation" error.

Comment: @aditya, updated code.. i was not using the correct context.. you need to pass `console` as the `this` argument to apply..

Comment: Just to point out, using this in your script will still cause errors in IE9 or older (or even IE10 if you're not using the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` tag) breaking your script on your first call to `log();` Instead of `if(console)` you should do `if(typeof(console) !== 'undefined')` which works in browsers new and old, including IE6-IE11.

Comment: Updated the answer to use typeof as @purefusion pointed out. There is no drawback

Comment: missing a { before console.log.apply

Answer (score 8):

There is a good example from the html5boilerplate code that wraps console.log in a similar way to make sure you don't disrupt any browsers that don't recognize it. It also adds a history and smoothes out any differences in the console.log implementation.

It was developed by Paul Irish and he has written up a post on it [here](http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/).

I've pasted the relevant code below, here is a link to the file in the project: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/js/plugins.js

```
// usage: log('inside coolFunc', this, arguments);
// paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/
window.log = function(){
  log.history = log.history || [];   // store logs to an array for reference
  log.history.push(arguments);
  if(this.console) {
    arguments.callee = arguments.callee.caller;
    var newarr = [].slice.call(arguments);
    (typeof console.log === 'object' ? log.apply.call(console.log, console, newarr) : console.log.apply(console, newarr));
  }
};

// make it safe to use console.log always
(function(b){function c(){}for(var d="assert,count,debug,dir,dirxml,error,exception,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,info,log,timeStamp,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,trace,warn".split(","),a;a=d.pop();){b[a]=b[a]||c}}((function(){try {console.log();return window.console;}catch(err){return window.console={};}})());
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

```
console.log.apply(null,arguments);
```

Although, you may need to loop through the arguments object and create a regular array from it, but apart from that that's how you do it.

Comment: This doesn't work in Chrome/Safari. It works in Firebug, but looking for a cross-browser solution here.

Comment: `args = []; for(i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) args.push(arguments[i]); console.log.apply(null,args);` - try that.

Comment: Nope. Apparently, any call to `console.log.apply` throws an Illegal invocation error.

Comment: Okay, what if you try `console.log(args.join(''));` instead of `console.log.apply` in my last bit of code?

Comment: That wouldn't be what I want. If one does `log({})`, it'll say `[object Object]` and not the usual.

Comment: Just change the `null` context to `console` and it works in every browser :) But that's the same as the accepted answer.. Oh well.